# How to comment code using a generic class of a specific type

Tags: c#, generics, comments

I'm trying to document my code in a proper way.

I have a method that can throw a FaultException of a specific type. When I view the documentation for the method it doesn't show the specific type of the FaultException.

```
///<summary>
/// Description of method
///</summary>
/// <exception cref="FaultException{ValidationFault}">Description here</exception>
OrganizationDto Update(UpdateOrganizationRequest organizationDto);
```

Documentation shows: ***FaultException<TDetail>***: Description here

I want it to show: ***FaultException<ValidationFault>***:Description here

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where are you viewing the "documentation"?

Comment: I am viewing it through either Resharpers quick documentation popup or through generated HTML files from Sandcastle. Both show the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on ReSharper version 8.2.2 and I can see the exception documentation like you wanted.

See screenshot:

[image: Exception Description on ReSharper 8.2.2]

On which version are you working on? maybe it is a defect related to this version?